# Is there a way to switch the "python [filename].py to a shortcut

Tags: python

Is there a way to switch the "python [filename].py to a shortcut like "shutdown" for example?

Comment: For ubuntu, you can create aliases in your bash file

Comment: This is an OS specific question. Can you specify an OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Linux, then go to the end of your bash configuration file (found at `~/.bashrc`), and add the line:

```bash
alias shutdown="python filename.py"
```

If you're on Windows, then create a file with the following line:

```
python filename.py
```

Then save the file as `shutdown.bat` and put it in your Windows directory (at `C:\WINDOWS`, also abbreviated as `%windir%`).